# How can I check a user is in a role in ASP MVC4 Simple Membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am familiar with:

```
WebSecurity.IsCurrentUserInRole("Admin")
```

But this does not seem to work any more. Is there another way I can check in my controller if a user is in a role when I am using SimpleMembership?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{

}
```

And webConfig

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    ....
```

After Comment

you can use something like this:

```
foreach (string rolesForUser in Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name))
{
    if (User.IsInRole(rolesForUser))
    {

    }
}
```

I think there is an elegant way to do this...

Comment: Thanks very much. I have taken note of your question and I want to post another now. As I wonder if there is a way to check if a user is in one of a few different kind of roles. I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to have a RoleProvider setup as well

Since you are using SimpleMembership, you probably should use `SimpleRoleProvider` as well.
You can either create the roles programatically by calling `Roles.CreateRole` or use the RoleManager web interface.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, 
                             WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>      
</roleManager>
```